# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on res.Render - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, ejs

I encounter an error on client side while sending a variable using res.Render().

I'd like to send an object with arrays in it:

NodeJs:

```
var countries_lat_lng = [];
        trip.countries.forEach(country => {
            var country_lat_lng = {'latlng': CountriesJSON.find(f => f.alpha2Code == country.code).latlng};
            countries_lat_lng.push(country_lat_lng);
        });
        console.log(countries_lat_lng); //value: [ { latlng: [ -27, 133 ] }, { latlng: [ -41, 174 ] } ]
        res.render('myView', {
            coutriesLatLng: {countries_lat_lng}
        });
```

Javascript:

```
        var countriesMarkers = <%= coutriesLatLng %>;
```

And I have this following error on chrome:

```
    var countriesMarkers = [object Object]; Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

When I console.log() my countries_lat_lng variable, everything seems to be ok but rendered In javascript I have an error.
Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<%= ... %>` is for outputting HTML, so what it's doing is converting your object to a string and HTML encoding it for output. Since you're generating JavaScript, what you want to do instead is to output the JSON of your data in a non-escaped format directly into your JS code.

Assuming `coutriesLatLng` is an `Array`, change this:

```
var countriesMarkers = <%= coutriesLatLng %>;
```

...to:

```
var countriesMarkers = <%- JSON.stringify(coutriesLatLng) %>;
```

The `JSON.stringify` will convert your Array to JSON, which is interpretable as a JavaScript expression. The `<%-` is for outputting that JSON without HTML-escaping it, so `"` doesn't become `&quot;`, for example.

Comment: Many many thanks ! Output is now good ! 

Thanks for taking your time for me!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var countriesMarkers = JSON.stringify('<%- coutriesLatLng %>');
```

Also I can see a problem here

```
res.render('myView', {
      coutriesLatLng: {countries_lat_lng}
});
```

I think this should be

```
res.render('myView', {
      coutriesLatLng: countries_lat_lng
});
```

Comment: I have the same error doing this :/ 

var countriesMarkers = JSON.parse([object Object]); Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Still not working but the error is not the same ^^

var countriesMarkers = JSON.parse([{&#34;latlng&#34;:[-27,133]},{&#34;latlng&#34;:[-41,174]}]);  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'